# How to decode and view Jboss JMS message content?

Tags: mysql, encoding, jboss, jms, blob

In `JBoss` `JBM_MSG table` (which stores JMS mq messages) the message content is a `longblob`. I am trying to view it in mySQL version is 5.1.67. I have tried variations of below, for all other character sets as well as utf8, but they don't work:

```
SELECT CONVERT(payload USING utf8) FROM JBM_MSG;

SELECT CAST(payload AS CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8) FROM JBM_MSG;
```

Another question on stackoverflow suggests JMS encoding is `utf16`, and my version of mySQL is `pre-utf16 support` - but table encoding is `latin1`.

Does anyone know how to view these messages?

Comment: they're binary objects in serialized form, you can't just expect java objects to be readable, right? or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks @eis, that could be it - I was presuming Jboss stored the JMS payload field as text, but it is more likely to be an object

Comment: text message is only one subtype of JMS, it doesn't have to be any kind of text

Answer (score 1):

JMS messages are java objects, and in the DB they would be in serialized form. Thus, you can't just convert them to be readable.